# Create folders from list within the parent folder of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to create a number of folders from a list in Col A, shared with the email address in col B.

Able to do it to create folders in My Drive, but I want to create the folders in the same folder that the sheet running the script is in.

so far I have:

```
function createFolders() {
  // Get the parent folder of the spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const parentFolder = sheet.getParent();
  const parentFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById;
  const folderIDnumber = parseInt(parentFolderId);

  // Get the values in column A and column B of the spreadsheet.
  const folderNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A:A").getValues();
  const emailAddresses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B:B").getValues();

  // Create a folder for each folder name in column A.
  for (let i = 0; i < folderNames.length; i++) {
    const folderName = folderNames[i][0];
    const emailAddress = emailAddresses[i][0];
    if (folderName) {
      const folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName, folderIDnumber);
      folder.addEditor(emailAddress);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The script shown has problems.  Where do take this code? What have you tried to debug and fix the code?

Comment: Yes, I know it has problems, thats why I'm here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createFolders() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  var parentFolder;
  const parents = file.getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    parentFolder = parents.next();
  }
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:B" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (r[0] && r[1]) {
      let folder = parentFolder.createFolder(r[0]);
      folder.addEditor(r[1]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Have tweaked a bit to this:
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(r[0]) {
      let folder = parentFolder.createFolder(r[0]);//using parent folder
      folder.addEditor(r[1]);
    }
  });
}        BUT - getting error Error 
Exception: Argument cannot be null: emailAddress
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:37
createFolders2 @ Code.gs:34